# Formula Generating Script Ignores Apostrophe Google Sheets GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a query where output is a condition met on all the tabs of a [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b-WEQSrKjSw4xHI9ofHYVo5nowCVTBabudCYHfP3njA/edit?usp=sharing).

```
QUERY({'01Dec2021'!A2:T},"select Col1 where Col1 !=''",1)
```

I wanted the sheet name to be included in the output, but only option seems to enter manually.

```
QUERY({'01Dec2021'!A2:T},"select Col1,'01Dec2021' where Col1 !=''",1)
```

I thought formula generating script can solve this problem which is this:

```
function Formula() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var formula = "={";
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var name = sheets[i].getName();
    if (name != "Master List" && name != "Summary") {
      formula = formula +"QUERY({"+ name + "!A2:T},select Col1,'"+name+"' where Col1 !='',1);";
    }
  }
  formula = formula.slice(0, -1) + '}'
  ss.getSheetByName("Summary").getRange("A2").setFormula(formula);
}
```

and while this solved the problem, I just can't figure out how to make the apostrophe as a text. I want to enter within apostrophe quotes like this "select Col1,'"+name+"' where Col1 !=''" but I can't do this without getting error.

```
formula = formula +"QUERY({"+ name + "!A2:T},select Col1,'"+name+"' where Col1 !='',1);"
```

I'd be thankful if someone can help me out to achieve this...

Comment: Use self contained question while asking for solution, the sheet you shared [actually expose your personal email address](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/is-it-ethical-to-ask-for-a-google-sheets-file-when-answering-a-question-even-w)  which is violating privacy norms.

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Template literals in your script with backticks

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

in your script:

```
function Formula() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var formula = "={";
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var name = sheets[i].getName();
    if (name != "Master List" && name != "Summary") {
      formula = formula + `QUERY({'${name}'!A2:T},"select Col1,'${name}' where Col1 is not null label '${name}' '' ",0);`;
    }
  }
  formula = formula.slice(0, -1) + '}'
  ss.getSheetByName("Summary").getRange("A2").setFormula(formula);
}
```